# DataGrid - TemplateFields with multiple datatypes for one column

Tags: c#, gridview

Can I possibly do this with DataGrid

```
|column1 | column 2   |
|r       | radiobutton| 
|s       | string     |
```

The entire DataGrid is to built dynamically from the server side code, so I can not define TemplateColumns/Fields at design time to hold radiobutton/label control

Will greatly appreciate any insights on how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure of your question - but you could use the ItemDataBound event, find the control you need in the item template or alternating item template - and then set the appropriate value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx